# Python socket receive bufsize parameter value

Tags: python, sockets

I am new to programming and started with Python about 2 weeks ago using a course on FCC, I am currently in the networking chapter.
The exercise was about creating a program which counts the maximum number of characters in a document of a website and only display the first 3000 characters of that document using the socket library in Python. The next exercise was to do the same with the urllib library. I have noticed that, when using socket, I was sometimes missing some letters in the file when the bufsize parameter of the `sock.recv(bufsize,[flag])` method wasn't set to the total length of received bytes from the document. For example when I used `1024` as the value for `bufsize`, there were some letters missing here and there from the retrieved document, but when I put the `bufsize` to `95000` (exact number of bytelength of that document), I got all the letters and everything worked fine.

Please don't be too harsh on me with the code, I am just starting to write something, but here is my example:

```
import socket
import re
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

while True:
    userinp = input("Enter a URL: ")
    try:
        if userinp.startswith("http"):
            url = userinp.split("/")[2]
            #print(url)
            sock.connect((url, 80))
            #print("http start connected")
            break
        elif userinp.startswith("www"):
            url = userinp.split("/")[0]
            #print(url)
            sock.connect((url, 80))
            #print("www start connected")
            break
        else:
            url = userinp.split("/")[0]
            #print(url)
            sock.connect((url, 80))
            #print("else start connected")
            break
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid URL")
        continue
if userinp.startswith("http:"):
    cmd0 = "GET " + userinp + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
    cmd = cmd0.encode()
    #print("http bytes: ", cmd)
elif userinp.startswith("https:"):
    cmd0 = "GET " + userinp + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + url + "\r\n\r\n"
    cmd = cmd0.encode()
    #print("https bytes: ", cmd)
else:
    cmd0 = "GET http://" + userinp + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
    cmd = cmd0.encode()
sock.send(cmd)
#print("cmd request sent")
count = 0
str = ""
while True:
    data = sock.recv(95000)      ##536 magic number in romeo.txt, 95000 in mbox-short.txt
    if len(data) < 1:            ##http://data.pr4e.org/mbox-short.txt
        break
    #print("Byte length:", len(data))
    data = data.decode()
    pos = data.find("\r\n\r\n") + 4
    for each in data[pos:]:
        count += 1
        if count <= 3000:
            str += each
print(str, "Total characters:", count, len(str))
sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
sock.close()
```

The first if statements are meant for the first exercise in the chapter, which was handling userinput URLs using the socket library. On many websites I have some problems with that too, since it often says

> 301: Moved Permanently

But the location specified in the document says it moved to the exact same location.\

#### So my questions are:

Why do I have to set the `bufsize` parameter to the exact bytelength of the retrieved document in order to get all letters out of it? Is there a way around this using the socket library?
Why do some websites specify that they are moved permanently, but show the exact same location of the website?
With the urllib library it is much easier, since it does "all the stuff" for me, but I would like to know how I need to write the program with the socket library too, just to get a better understanding of it.

I'm sorry for the noob questions, but I've read that beginner questions are welcome aswell! I hope you can help me with my problem, thank you in advance! :)

Comment: sockets are somewhat lower level than you are prepared for. The `bufsize` argument represents the **maximum** amount of data that the `recv()` call will return to you. In reality, it will return whatever data is currently available in the internal receive buffer or 95000 bytes, whichever is smaller. This means, for example, that you the server may send 95000 bytes and after returning from `data = sock.recv(95000)` data may only have 100 bytes in it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I will look up more on networking and sockets and everything once I finished the first course, looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, before HTTP/1.1, `Content-Length` header is *SHOULD* on [RFC1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.4), of course this means the header was not required. How did application distinguish end of file, closing of TCP connection was regarded as it. Therefore, there are files of which we can't know
size before downloading even now. This story is about HTTP, layer 7, application layer in [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

Sockets which you use belong TCP, layer 5 and 4. TCP doesn't have how to know size of files. It just manages connections and sends bytes only. It doesn't think any other thing. If TCPs work correctly each other, other layers are guaranteed to work. This is same as HTTP too.

*How network works?* is itself able theme to be written a thick book. If you are interested in, I recommend to read some books about network.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I actually used a different method to add the received bytes from the .recv method and added an empty bytearray before the loop, which I then used to add the data too before the for loop in the example. Because it wasn't part of the for loop I received all the data and could go on working with that bytearray, which was easier for me. I just tried it a minute ago or so ^^ As to the networking layers and how the network works, I would love to know and read about it, but I want to finish the course first and then read about stuff like networking aso. Thanks again!

Comment: Also if you have any recommendations on good books about the basic understanding of networks and so on, please let me know (but please really beginner stuff, just starting my journey) :)

Comment: I'm afraid that I know only the books written in Japanese. I don't know about website also. If ask with quoting this answer again, you might get information. I was thinking advice a lot, but can't summarize it well. Anyway, detailed question which you asked must be replied good answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! When I finished the course, I will ask for good recommendation on this forum again, looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in the answer to this question (probably not, because it is a complete beginner question):
I played around with the program a little and added print statements basically everywhere to be able to see what it is doing at what point exactly. The received data every time in the sock.recv is set to 512, so it sends 512 bytes worth of information per iteration of that loop. Then those 512 bytes of information will be used by the for loop after decoding it to a string, iterating through every character of the string but only up to the end of those 512 bytes of information, which in this case (romeo.txt) ends with the "s" in the last line of the poem. Then the sock.recv starts receiving the rest of the information of the document and the for loop starts iterating through the rest again, but this time because of the "data[pos:]" (initially used to remove the header) it starts at the beginning position of those remaining bytes + 4. So with this I would have 3 letters less for each iteration of the loops.

Comment: Yes, thank you again! Will create a new post when I finished the course, which will probably still take a while to do so ^^ See you around! :)